# How to mock out custom throttle class for testing in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-rest-framework

I have a custom throttle class like: (print statements are for debugging ***:)***) in `api.throttle.py`

```py
print("befor CustomThrottle class")
class CustomThrottle(BaseThrottle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("initializing CustomThrottle", self)
        self._wait = 0

    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        print("CustomThrottle.allow_request")
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        # some checking here
        if wait > 0:
            self._wait = wait
            return False
        return True

    def wait(self):
        return self._wait
```

my `api.views.py` is like:

```py
from api.throttle import CustomThrottle

print("views module")
class SomeView(APIView):
    print("in view")
    throttle_classes = [CustomThrottle]

    def post(self, request, should_exist):
        # some processing
        return Response({"message": "Done."})
```

and my tests is `api/tests/test_views.py`:

```py
    @patch.object(api.views.CustomThrottle, "allow_request")
    def test_can_get_confirmation_code_for_registered_user(self, throttle):
        throttle.return_value = True
        response = self.client.post(path, data=data)
        self.assertEqual(
            response.status_code,
            status.HTTP_200_OK,
            "Should be successful",
        )

    @patch("api.views.CustomThrottle")
    def test_learn(self, throttle):
        throttle.return_value.allow_request.return_value = True
        response = self.client.post(path, data=data)
        self.assertEqual(
            response.status_code,
            status.HTTP_200_OK,
            "Should be successful",
        )
```

the first test passes correctly but still the `CustomThrottle` class is instantiated but the `allow_request` method is mocked; the second test shows that neither `CustomThrottle` class is mocked nor the `allow_request` method and it fails with `status 429` (`CustomThrottle` has a throttle rate of 2 minutes).

Comment: Do you want to mock, `CustomThrottle` within the second test, am I right?

Comment: @myuz, Yes, in the first test the `allow_request` method is mocked but in the second one I want the whole `CustomThrottle` class to be mocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time and testing different scenarios (Putting debug like print statements here and there ***:)*** ) I finally found out why it's not working, **But it may not be as correct as I think so any better answer is welcome**.

I defined list of throttle classes like `throttle_classes = [CustomThrottle]` so when server starts it's imported and evaluated so there's a reference to the actual and unmocked version of `CustomThrottle` in my `SomeView` class and when processing the responses it will use that for instantiation and so my test fails, but when I patch it like `patch.object(CustomThrottle, "allow_request")` when view actually needs to check throttles it will call something like `CustomThrottle().allow_request(...)` (pay attention to parentheses for object creation); the object has not a method like `allow_request` in itself so it searches that in it's class and use the mocked version correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want also to mock `CustomThrottle` class, and his properties, you also need to `patch` in places where do you need it, because of `patch` decorator applies `monkey patching` in places where you calling it.

Regarding your case, you able to do something like

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

    @patch('api.views.CustomThrottle')
    @patch('api.views.PhoneConfirmationThrottle')
    def test_learn(self, phone_throttle, custom_throttle):
        mocked_custom_throttle_instance = MagicMock()
        mocked_custom_throttle_instance.allow_request = True
        mocked_custom_throttle_instance.status = ...

        # Do some stuff which do you need with the mocked class
        # and then return an instance for your patched object

        custom_throttle.return_value = mocked_custom_throttle_instance

        response = self.client.post(path, data=data)
        self.assertEqual(
            response.status_code,
            status.HTTP_200_OK,
            "Should be successful",
        )
```

It will replace your `real` object with the `mocked` one, also check out [unittest.mock documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html), it will help you in the future.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in question, I used patch like `@patch('api.views.CustomThrottle')` but it's not mocking the class my view uses.

Comment: where is `mocked_custom_throttle_instance` coming from?

Comment: You're defining within a test, `mocked_custom_throttle_instance = MagicMock()`

And then you're returning it for a patched object `custom_throttle.return_value = mocked_custom_throttle_instance`, it helped you?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've used this way, posted an answer; I suggest you to review it.